# C# WPF SizeChanged event doesn't update width and height when maximized

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, dpi

I was trying to update my controls when the size of the form changed using `SizeChanged`.

It worked perfectly, except when going full screen.

I searched the grid events but couldn't find any events that occur when the user maximizes the window (goes full screen).

Comment: According to the documentation, `When the WindowState property is changed, StateChanged is raised`. And indeed it does.

Comment: @IvanStoev it does but it doesn't help me because i need it as a event , this will make me put a timer or something so can check weather it has changed or not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to receive `SizeChanged` event on maximize:

```
private void window1_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var a = window1.ActualHeight;
    var b = window1.ActualWidth;
    var c = window1.Height;
    var d = window1.Width;
}
```

And these are values for window `Height` and `Width`:

> a = 838.4
>   b   = 1550.4
>   c   = 350.4
>   d   = 524.8

Comment: bro thank you much , this is so simple and solved my problem :) , i still don't get why i got -1 on my post , thanks again bro

Comment: You're welcome, Sir. I think it was a fair question so i gave you +1.